# Queria dar um droptable nas tags

Tags: debate, tags

Essa imagem abaixo mostram algumas tags registradas iniciando como **Android**. A questão que quero levantar é: Porque existe *android-activity* se activity está relacionado a Android? *android-eclipse* seria isso mesmo ou seria melhor ter duas tags separadamente?

Por exemplo, uso o **Android** no **Eclipse**. Qual a melhor maneira de usar a tag "*android-eclipse*" ou "*android*","*eclipse*" separadamente? Por desencargo de consciência, as vezes uso das duas maneiras, mas ainda não sei qual maneira correta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pra te falar a verdade, eu acho todas as tags ai uteis. Por mais que activity possa lembrar imediatamente android, é bom essa tag composta que mostra claramente essa relação, até na hora de pesquisar também. E pense mais para frente: hoje activity pode ter a ver só com android, mas se num futuro essa palavra criar relação comum com outra linguagem ou ambiente?

Comment: Para mim `[android-activity]` faz sentido pela razão que você aponta para não. As tags devem poder existir sozinhas, `[activity]` seria ambígua, não vejo como possa ser utilizada só. Há tempos foi-me pedida a opinião sobre se devia existir ou não a tag `[android-eclipse]`, na altura justifiquei a sua existência por haver questões iguais que tem tratamento/resposta diferente caso esteja a ser utilizado o Android Studio ou o Eclipse. O meu entendimento sobre as tags tem evoluído, fruto das várias discussões levantadas no Meta, neste momento não tenho tanta certeza se deverá existir.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Porque existe android-activity se activity está relacionado a Android?

Exactamente por essa razão.

As tags devem poder existir sozinhas, `[activity]`(actividade) seria ambígua, não vejo como possa ser utilizada só.

> android-eclipse seria isso mesmo ou seria melhor ter duas tags separadamente?

Aceito que possa ser discutível, mas não vejo mal algum na sua utilização:

- Há questões iguais que tem tratamento/resposta diferente caso esteja a ser utilizado o Android Studio ou o Eclipse.
- Existem questões que, apesar da IDE ser o Eclipse, elas são exclusivas da utilização da IDE no desenvolvimento Android.

Na mesma linha estão as tags `[android-service]`, `[android-adapter]`, `[android-permission]`, etc, porque *service*, *adapter* e *permission* têm, no contexto do Android, um entendimento diferente(especifico) do que em outros contextos.

Por outro lado há a limitação de 5 *tags* por pergunta, se existissem apenas tags abrangentes poderia ser difícil classificá-las de forma a serem encontradas quando o critério for estreito.

Comment: Pois bem, esta questão _android-eclipse_ que me fez pensar um pouco. Mas concordo que a tag _activity_ sozinha fica muito vago.